# infinispan - encoding type - not showing items

Tags: caching, encoding, marshalling, infinispan, keycloak-connect

running keycloak + infinispan standalone well.

problem: when using infinispan Server management Console,
data container doesn't show real items.
wheng checkin sessions tab.  --> empty

page show this message.
**This cache uses "application/x-jboss-marshalling" for keys and "application/x-jboss-marshalling" encoding for values. Infinispan Console might not fully support data manipulation or displaying entries for caches that don't use ProtoStream encoding.**

i am using application/x-jboss-marshalling  both for,  (cache-ispn.xml)keycloak,  infinispan.xml(infinispan)

- (cache-ispn.xml)keycloak

```
        <distributed-cache name="authenticationSessions" owners="2">
            <remote-store xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:store:remote:14.0"
                          cache="authenticationSessions"
                          purge="false"
                          preload="false"
                          segmented="false"
                          shared="true"
                          raw-values="true"
                          marshaller="org.keycloak.cluster.infinispan.KeycloakHotRodMarshallerFactory">
                <remote-server host="10.157.37.50" port="11222" />
                <security>
                    <authentication server-name="infinispan">
                        <digest username="admin" password="password" realm="default"/>
                    </authentication>
                </security>
            </remote-store>
        </distributed-cache>
```

- infinispan.xml(infinispan)

```
    <distributed-cache name="authenticationSessions">
            <encoding media-type="application/x-jboss-marshalling"/>
    </distributed-cache>
```

message saying that use "ProtoStream encoding" to show real items.
how can i use "ProtoStream encoding"  in (cache-ispn.xml)keycloak,  infinispan.xml(infinispan)?

thanks

i changeed like below

- infinispan.xml(infinispan)

```
      <jgroups>
         <stack name="jdbc-ping-tcp" extends="tcp">
         <JDBC_PING connection_driver="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
                     connection_username="root" connection_password="root@123"
                     connection_url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cluster-information"
                     initialize_sql="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS JGROUPSPING (own_addr varchar(200) NOT NULL, cluster_name varchar(200) NOT NULL, ping_data BINARY(124), constraint PK_JGROUPSPING PRIMARY KEY (own_addr, cluster_name));"
                     info_writer_sleep_time="500"
                     remove_all_data_on_view_change="true"
                     stack.combine="REPLACE"
                     stack.position="MPING" />
         </stack>
   </jgroups>  

 <cache-container name="remoteKeycloak" statistics="true">
      <transport cluster="${infinispan.cluster.name:globalCluster}" stack="jdbc-ping-tcp" node-name="${infinispan.node.name:mainNode}" site="site1"/>
    <distributed-cache name="authenticationSessions">
            <encoding media-type="**application/application/x-protostream**"/>
    </distributed-cache>
```

- (cache-ispn.xml)keycloak

```
        <distributed-cache name="authenticationSessions" owners="2">
            <remote-store xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:store:remote:14.0"
                          cache="authenticationSessions"
                          purge="false"
                          preload="false"
                          segmented="false"
                          shared="true"
                          raw-values="true"
                          marshaller="**org.infinispan.protostream**">
                <remote-server host="10.157.37.50" port="11222" />
                <security>
                    <authentication server-name="infinispan">
                        <digest username="admin" password="password" realm="default"/>
                    </authentication>
                </security>
            </remote-store>
        </distributed-cache>
```

but it makes error.